# image.seturl(string ) not working

Tags: gwt

when i give  Image image = new Image(d5); in gwt

```
image.setUrl(url1.toString());
```

and url1 is a string the it will how show the image but directly if a give the url the it will work proprly ...i have the url in tha string and wana to set in image ....

Answer (score 0):

What is d5 for you?

I guess you need this:

```
Image image = new Image(url1);
```